# Getting code that would self build a python data structure

Tags: python, serialization, data-structures

Is there a way where I'm able to generate the code in a file for a python data structure.

For example, if I had a dictionary, it would create a file with:
name_of_variable = { key: value, key:value}

and so on. The use for this is testing where I don't want to manually code up a lot of data structures for my tests and I'd rather create some template structures where I can edit manually.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simple data structures such `dict`, `list`, `set` and other built-in things you can use `repr()`:

```
>>> d = {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 4}
>>> repr(d)
"{'a': 2, 'c': 4, 'b': 3}"
>>> l = range(10)
>>> repr(l)
'[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]'
>>> s = set(range(10))
>>> repr(s)
'set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])'
```

[Documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr) says: ''For many types, this function makes an attempt to return a string that would yield an object with the same value when passed to `eval()`''.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use JSON serialization. Since 2.6, Python has the `json` module in the *standard library*, and using it is really simple:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(['foo', {'bar': ('baz', None, 1.0, 2)}])
'["foo", {"bar": ["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]'
```

You can place this string in a file. Later you can read it back into a Python data structure with `json.loads`.

---

However, I'd also like to separately address this quote from your question:

> I don't want to manually code up a lot
>   of data structures for my tests and
>   I'd rather create some template
>   structures where I can edit manually.

If this is for testing purposes, I would seriously consider staying in the domain of Python code & data structures, and generate test data on the fly with Python code. The specifics of this are very much dependent on the exact nature of *your* data, but writing such data structures manually is a not a welcome task. You'll become bored too quickly to get good coverage of your code.

Comment: @pst: when all you need is serialization of Python data structures, JSON is IMHO a far better choice than XML

Comment: I'm not serious about XML ;-)

Comment: @pst: yeah. thankfully, XML is not very popular among Python hackers

Answer (score 1):

Another Human-Friendly serialization format is [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) which can be accessed through the [PyYAML](http://pyyaml.org) module....

...or, for the quick'n'dirty `import` the module containing POP ("Plain Old Python") ;-)

Happy coding.